# From one php file I need to pass two ajax variables to two independent javascript files in the same isset condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In php file:

```
if(isset($_POST["my_first_variable"]))
{
   if(empty($_POST["my_first_variable"]))
   {
      //This $rtrn variable I need to return to another ajax function in 
      another javascript file

      $rtrn["my_return_second_variable"]="First variable is empty";
      echo json_encode($rtrn);
   }
}
```

From first javascript file I send input data variable to php, where I check If that value is not empty and correct , If it is I need to send returning data to another javascript file that tells that input is empty or incorrect to disable submit button on main page.

Comment: You cannot choose where to send a server response. The JS code which makes the AJAX request receives the response. Once your AJAX call has received the response then your JS needs to execute whatever code you want.

Comment: In this isset condition data is always returned to first ajax function which is in first.js file. How to receive part of data in second.js file. This echo json_encode($rtrn); is returning data to first.js file. But I need that to be passed to second.js.

Comment: Yes correct, so `first.js` needs to send the data to `second.js`.

Comment: Ohh, that is great. Can you tell me how to do this. And post that as an answer to close the question. Is that in ajax function???

Comment: Ok, answer posted. Does it help you to understand the concept?

Comment: Yeahh. You helped me so much. I will use this concept to finish my project. Thank you so much again! I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP cannot arbitrarily send data to some random file. It sends data back to the file which requested it.

You need your Javascripts to communicate with each other:

**myscript.php**

```
if(isset($_POST["my_first_variable"]))
{
   if(empty($_POST["my_first_variable"]))
   {
      //This $rtrn variable I need to return to another ajax function in 
      another javascript file

      $rtrn["my_return_second_variable"]="First variable is empty";
      echo json_encode($rtrn);
   }
}
```

**first.js**

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'www.example.com/myscript.php', // Send a request with POST data to this file
        type: 'POST', // Send as a POST and not GET
        data: { 'my_first_variable' : '' }, // Make sure this data is set but empty to satisfy the logic in myscript.php
        dataType: 'json', // We expect to receive JSON data
        success: function( data ){
            doSomething( data ); // Send this data to second.js
        }
    });
});
```

**second.js**

```
function doSomething( incomingData ){
    alert( incomingData[ 'my_return_second_variable' ] );
}
```

Make sure to load both of these files and it should work.

---

For the sake of anyone using Google, some common search phrases could be:

- How to send data from one JS file to another?
- How can PHP split which JS files receive data?
- Pass data from one Js file to another.